# c++ Adding 100 numbers to each other

Tags: c++

I know most of people may find this too easy but i am still very new to programming so i need a program that allows the user to enter 100 numbers and the program finds their sum , i have tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
float x;
int counter=0 , sum=0;


cout<<"enter a number\n";
cin>>x;
do {
        sum+=x;
        cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;
        counter++;  
   } 
while ( counter<=100 );
}
```

i found this making 'x' has the value that i entered first time but i need to enter different value every time it repeats (entering 100 different values) what should i add?

Comment: Put `cin >> x` inside the loop. By the way, it's probably not a good idea to ask the user to input 100 numbers ...

Comment: Thanks i have missed that one and yes it's  non sense but i am just practicing random things just to understand the concepts

Comment: try running your program by hand, and also [learn how to debug first](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the input prompt and cin into the loop

```
do
{
    cout << "enter a number\n";
    cin >> x
    sum += x;
    cout << "sum=" << sum << endl;
    counter++;
}
while (counter < 100);
```

Take note that it should be `counter < 100` instead of `counter <= 100` if you want it to be exactly 100 times.

Comment: Thank you ... that helped , i also didn't notice that "counter" mistake i will keep that in mind next time .

Answer (score 0):

You just have put the cin into the loop so that in every iteration it asks for an input.
Also note that the variable sum is an integer, while the variable x is a float.
So you probably should make sum a float or make x an integer to avoid getting unexpected results .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  float x,sum=0;
  int counter=0 ;



  do {
      cout<<"enter a number\n";
      cin>>x;
      sum+=x;
      cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;
      counter++;  
     } while ( counter<=100 );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [For loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) also for simplicity. Make sure to use [long int](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) data type for storing sum because the sum of 100 integers may lead to [integer overflow](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x, num;
    long int sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter the number you want to find the sum:";
    cin>>num;    // Like 100
    for(int counter=1;counter<=num;counter++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a number:";
        cin>>x;
        sum+=x;
    }
    cout<<"Sum of "<<num<<" numbers is:"<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it in a for loop:

```
float input, sum;
    for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++){
       cout << "Enter a number << endl;
       cin >> input;
       sum += input;
       cout << "sum is: << sum << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Look out** at the condition of your while. You are saying this -> counter<=100, and counter is initialized to 0. So, you will enter from 0 to 100(included) = 101 times. If you only want to enter 100 times, the condition should be

```
do
{
    cout << "enter a number\n";
    cin >> x
    sum += x;
    cout << "sum=" << sum << endl;
    counter++;
}
while (counter < 100);
```

or initialize counter to 1, and then you can use the same while as you had.